# What tools one can use to detect a malicious activity on a computer, aside from antivirus programs?

Tags: windows, security, internet, internet-connection, anti-virus

Some time ago I got a virus on my computer, which is not detected by antivirus programs.
Yet I can see the malicious activity in the Windows Event Log and in the TcpLogView:

[image]

Considering that updates of antivirus databases always lag behind the creation of new viruses, what program tools are best suited for a timely detection of such zero-day threats?

Comment: Security programs that have signature based on a signatures behavior

Comment: A separate firewall that does not operate within windows.  Say another computer with 2 NIC.  pfSense firewall, and run snort, or some other IPS.  It can detect and block traffic before it reaches your PC.  Even a rootkit will not be able to evade the firewall block (of the destination IP) as its on its own PC.  The firewall should eventually block every IP used in the attack, plus it should have its own black/white lists. Typically you need to have a series of 4+ tools for stubborn or rootkit like tools.

Comment: @cybernard An expanded version of this would make for an interesting answer.

Comment: Guy @andhisdog I'm curious how you know that the above events were generated by a virus. I don't see anything obviously wrong with them.

Comment: @jpaugh What areas should I expand on in my answer?

Comment: @jpaugh, I know this because firstly I am not in Singapore. Not even close. There is no good reason why SYSTEM from my computer would try to connect to a remote computer located in Singapore 60 times per minute, each time trying a different port. Secondly, later on I found from the Windows Event Log that exactly at that time, that exact IP made an anonymous logon into my computer. And there is absolutely no non-malicious way how that could possibly happen.

Comment: @JakeGould, that is just one of the screenshots that I made back then. I believe I got this virus on the 11th or 12th of April. The virus is still in my computer, but the antivirus software can not find anything relevant. Looks like some sort of rootkit/worm/EternalBlue-like SMB exploit, hopefully not a RAT.

Comment: @Ramhound, would you care to elaborate?

Comment: @cybernard, the info is interesting. But this particular question is about software tools, and it is about detection, not prevention. Like what malware does and how one can detect it. For example, a virus had created an account on my computer using a stolen credentials. Thus there is no way for an antivirus to tell if the account is malicious or not. But I can tell, just by looking on the list of accounts. That sort of thing.

Comment: @andhisdog There are two ways security software identify malicious software.  Signatures based on their behavior and signatures based on a file hash.  One only can identify malicious software that matches the signature the other can identify a specific program behavior.  I won't go into anymore detail since this question is extremely broad.  If you want help identifying your malicious infection come to chat.

Comment: @Ramhound The question is asked in a broad sense, it is not about solving my particular problem (though I am interested in solving it). Say, right now you are certain that there are no viruses on your computer. But how can you be certain? Do you use any tools aside form antivirus programs? Do you monitor connections? Do you monitor ports? Do you check some other things? Because my antiviruses detect nothing, and I know that my computer is infected, and so could be yours.

Comment: Question ask in a broad sense is too broad.  "But how can you be certain?" - Content filtering.

Answer (score 1):

A good rootkit can not be detected by any antivirus software running on the host computer.  However, most rootkit depend on a command and control server somewhere.  Since it is going across the internet the IP addresses and dns names can be blocked by a computer between the ISP and your computer.

I have setup a VM using a computer dedicated to vmware esxi server.  The internet goes into that VM before being allowed on my network.  I have also got a pfSense firewall running in another VM.  pfSense has snort built-into it as a tool.  Snort is an industry recognized bad guy detection tool.  It can automatic block IP or dns names.

Addition vendors have more black and white lists which they automatically update.

My own firewall can also detect and block suspicious IP addresses which randomly reach out to me to a see if certain ports are open.  This is the first stage of an attack called recon, it does no damage but they build database so they know who to attack and how later on.

Many AV vendors now provide bootable CD/DVD,USB, or ISO images for scanning windows without windows running so they can at least hope to find the rootkits.  I frequently use several tools like Norton and Malwarebytes to scan my system, but in some cases you may need 2 or 3 different products to find the virus.

However, virus writers are testing their AV products against their viruses to make sure they can't find them.

Many AV products rely on virus signatures to detect viruses, but today those are not very useful and you need AV that detects the behaviors of a virus and not the signature.

Comment: So far I scanned my computer with HijackThis, RogueKiller, Junkware Removal Tool, Malwarebytes Antimalware, Malwarebytes Anti-Rootkit, COMODO Cleaning Essentials, Farbar Recovery Scan Tool, - no luck as of yet. TcpLogView seems helpful, but it only works for TCP, while the viruses use other protocols as well. And I have no idea what is going on there. They hijack SYSTEM with stolen credentials, Firewall lets them out since SYSTEM is a trusted process. They seem to hijack svchost and lsass as well.